# Are hostnames permanent? Can I change it?

Tags: python, ip-address, hostname

Sorry for the general questions but I am not deep into the subject and the info I am finding in the internet is very confusing to me. I am trying to retrieve data from a sensor that is connected to the wifi, and for it I need to call a function that has this sensor's IP Address as a parameter. Therefore, when the IP Address changes, I need to keep rewriting the IP Address on my script. I have found this way to get the IP Address of the sensor. Assuming my sensor's hostname is "mydevice".

```
hostname = "mydevice"
ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
```

I found out the hostname of my sensor using an IP Scanner App on my phone to just get the info of the devices that are on my network. The problem is that if I take the sensor to another place and use another wifi, it doesn't show a hostname in this app anymore. I am very confused and therefore I have the following questions.

1. I know each device has a hostname. Is this hostname permanent and can it be used in different WiFi networks?
2. If the hostname is not permanent, can I somehow set it to be permanent?
3. If I cannot set the hostname permanently, can I somehow include code in my python script so that the ip address of my sensor is retrieved every time the script runs, in case there are any changes?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You need to use DNS. Setup a DNS server for your sensors,

Comment: Hi and thanks. But my main question is if the hostname is permanent, cause if it is, I can just use the code above and it will work every time.

Comment: The hostname provided by DNS is. You can't use the node hostname for lookup like so

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate a bit more? Like maybe point me to some links that might be useful? I am trying to read about DNS but I feel like it's more complicated than what I need. If you could roughly explain the steps that would help a lot. THanks

Comment: `gethostbyname` performs a DNS lookup. It's basically mapping a name to an IP. To do that you need to set up DNS. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html

Comment: @xoani: Just to clarify... there are external (public) IP addresses, which are used to communicate across the internet, and there are internal (private, local) IP addresses, which your router assigns to the devices, such as your phone, on your local wifi network. Which type of IP address are you referring to?

Comment: hi @evergreen and thanks for your reply. To be honest I don't know anything about IP-Addresses. The only thing I want, is that I can take my sensor and my Raspberry Pi to different households and that the sensor's IP is somehow recognized in the Python Script that I got running on the Raspberry Pi. I am guessing this is just a local address (?)

Comment: Each device has a unique hardware address called a MAC address. It's possible it's marked on the device itself. The best place to find it is from the list of devices on your router, if you can tell which device it is. Once you have that, google for ways to get the local IP on any given network from the MAC address. The MAC address of the sensor will never change; it will be a string of hex numbers like this: ac:23:0b:9f:19:1f. I have never done this myself, so I can't offer any links.

Comment: @evergreen yes I have the MAC address. Thanks, I will try that out :)